# gcc vs clang - ambiguous overload when using `make_overload` variadic lambda inheritance

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang, c++14

Time for another round of **clang vs gcc**. [Live example on godbolt.org](https://goo.gl/RDPCKD).

---

**Test 0**: overloaded callable object

```
struct Trad
{
    auto operator()(int)    { return 1; }
    auto operator()(float)  { return 2; }
    auto operator()(double) { return 3; }
};

int main()
{
    assert(Trad{}(1) == 1);
    assert(Trad{}(1.f) == 2);
    assert(Trad{}(1.0) == 3);
}
```

- g++ 5.2 compiles and run.
- clang++ 3.5 *(and later versions)* compiles and run.

---

**Test 1**: overloaded callable object, generated via lambda inheritance

```
template <typename... TFs>
struct overload_set : TFs...
{
    overload_set(TFs... fs) : TFs(fs)... {}
};

template <typename... TFs>
auto overload(TFs&&... fs)
{
    return overload_set<TFs...>{fs...};
}

int main()
{
    auto func = overload 
    (
        [](int)    { return 1; }, 
        [](float)  { return 2; }, 
        [](double) { return 3; }
    );

    assert(func(1) == 1);
    assert(func(1.f) == 2);
    assert(func(1.0) == 3);
}
```

- g++ 5.2 does not compile.

  - > error: request for member 'operator()' is ambiguous
- clang++ 3.5 *(and later versions)* compiles and run.

---

What compiler is correct here?

Comment: MSVS2015 will compile the second example but the intellisense does not like it.

Comment: This is a dupe of...something. Anyway, GCC is right.

Comment: @T.C: why is GCC right? ...shouldn't the code generated by `make_overload` be equivalent to `struct Trad { ... }`? Is there any workaround to make `make_overload` work?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Try `struct Trad0 { auto operator()(int){return 1;}};` etc, then `struct Trad:Trad0, Trad1, Trad2 {` etc.  Notice when you call `operator()` on *this* version of `Trad`, the same ambiguity occurs.  Basically, overload rules don't work the way you want them to when the overloads are picked between distinct bases provided methods, where no `using` occurs to move them to the same scope: instead, you get "ambiguous".

Comment: @t.c. I have seen this before here to.  I didn't remember which one was right, just that to get it to work consistently you have to jump through certain hoops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you a workaround.

```
template <typename... TFs>
struct overload_set : TFs...
{
  overload_set(TFs... fs) : TFs(fs)... {}
};
```

here, we inherit from a bunch of distinct parent types, each with an `operator()`.  These do not (at least in gcc) overload the way you want.

To fix this, we inherit linearly and carry `()` down via `using`:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct inherit_linearly;
template<>
struct inherit_linearly<>{};
template<class T0, class...Ts>
struct inherit_linearly<T0, Ts...>:
  T0, inherit_linearly<Ts...>
{
   using T0::operator();
   using inherit_linearly<Ts...>::operator();
   template<class A0, class...As>
   inherit_linearly( A0&&a0, As&&...as ):
     T0(std::forward<A0>(a0)),
     inherit_linearly<Ts>(std::forward<As>(as)...) 
   {}
};
```

now we replace `overload_set` as follows:

```
template <typename... TFs>
struct overload_set : inherit_linearly<TFs...>
{
  using inherit_linearly<TFs...>::operator();
  overload_set(TFs... fs) :
    inherit_linearly<TFs...>(std::forward<TFs>(fs)...)
  {}
};
```

and both gcc and clang should like it.

The linear inheritance is sub-optimal: a balanced binary tree is better, but would take more work.  (basically, you take a pack `Xs...` and you split it into `Xs_front...` and `Xs_back...` using careful TMP, put those in a `types<...>` pack, transcribe those to your two parents, and do the `using blah::operator()` thing).  This is because the compiler has a limit on recursive template instantiations and inheritance depth that tends to be more shallow than the limit of total template instantiations and inheritance "volume".

---

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) we don't have to do this linear inheritance:

```
template <typename... TFs>
struct overload_set : TFs...
{
  using TFs::operator()...;
  overload_set(TFs... fs) : TFs(fs)... {}
};
```

because they added a new spot you can do `...` expansion.

Comment: Thanks. Found [another workaround](https://github.com/mnmlstc/core/blob/master/include%2Fcore%2Finternal.hpp#L136-L164) as well.

Comment: For completeness you should declare a `operator()` in the explicit specialization of `inherit_linearly`, otherwise the code will fail almost always.

Comment: @joh yep, or add a 1 arg spec.  Feel free to edit, am on phone.